# How did "Songs of Innocence and Experience" inspire "Airbag" by Radiohead?

Tags: song-lyrics, inspiration, songs-of-innocence, ok-computer, radiohead

Apparently, some of the lyrics to Radiohead's "Airbag" [were found written in the margins of a volume of Songs of Innocence and Experience](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/12157549/Radiohead-OK-Computer-song-lyrics-inspired-by-William-Blake-poems.html).

Was this song inspired or influenced by Songs of Innocence and Experience? Was the writer effectively trying to categorize this as a "Song of Experience"?